# Permission denied when trying to run program copied from another computer

Tags: linux, bash, permissions

I compiled a program which has the permission of (-rwxr-xr-x), and I copied this executable file to another PC. When I try to run it the warning says "Permission denied".

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: can you post the result of ls -la command?

Comment: How did you copy it?

Comment: Please show the full error message.  Is it permission on the script file itself, the binary in the #! line, or some data file or directory which the script tries to access?  Without the whole error message there is no way of knowing.

Answer (score 0):

Try `chmod +x <filename>`

Seems like the permissions were changed during copy.

Also, please share how did you copy, maybe this can be avoided.

chmod will change the file permissions.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod